# Issue in starting domain in Glassfish server

Tags: java-ee-7, glassfish-4

I am trying to start a domain for GlassFish. Changed security properties for felix folder. But it is giving error as

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@498dfd69
>   in service registry.

I am using Windows 7. 
[image: screenshot of error]

Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working fine now. problem was I gave all permission to felix folder as an administrator but not as a local user.

thanks